# A-Frame: How do I create movable entities on click?

Tags: javascript, html, aframe

I'm trying to make an A-Frame game in which the user can create houses. 
I already made house templates for 4 different houses (obj models). Each house shows an individual name on hover. 
I also have 4 "buttons" (boxes) which should create a house. The user should be able to click on a button to create a house which is movable and nameable (with the attached text on a plane). After it's named and moved to the desired position it should be saved. Is that even possible?

This is what I have (for one house):

```html
<a-obj-model src="#basic-house-obj" scale=".015 .015 .015" position="-1.958 0 -4.376" color="red" change-color-on-hover="color: #4CC3D9"
                event-set__enter="_event: mouseenter; _target: #modelBox; visible: true"
                event-set__leave="_event: mouseleave; _target: #modelBox; visible: false">
        <a-plane id="modelBox" hide-on-click visible="false" position="-35.872 135 23.300" material="opacity:0.4; color: black; side: front" scale="100 200">
            <a-text id="houseTitle" value="Test Kindergarden" align="center" color="#fff" position="0 0.4 0" scale="0.5 0.5 20"></a-text>
          </a-plane>
   </a-obj-model>
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want the click a button, where you listen using a click event listener, and then create a house from a template (e.g., `document.createElement` + `.setAttribute`s), has a text entity attached as a child, and be able to move it using either cursor / mouse / or VR hand controllers?

Comment: Yes exactly! So can I just use the templating component? But how do I make an "edit house" mode after creating a house? It should be movable and nameable right after creating it. Thank you for your answer!